# Firestore security rules for batched writes. How do they work?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

If the client code is supposed to do a **batched write** to Firestore like the following:

[DOC: Transactions and Batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes)

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const batch = db.batch();

// UPDATE CITY POPULATION IN CITIES COLLECTION

const docRef = db.collection('CITIES').doc('NYC');
batch.update(nycRef, {population: 10000000});

// UPDATE CITY POPULATION IN ALL_CITIES_POPULATIONS COLLECTION

const docRef = db.collection('ALL_CITIES_POPULATION').doc('ALL_CITIES_POPULATION');
batch.update(docRef, {
  NYC: 1000000
});
```

On the 1st update, I'm updating a property on the `NYC` doc on the `CITIES` collection.

On the 2nd update, I'm updating a property named `NYC` on the `ALL_CITIES_POPULATION` doc, that is on the `ALL_CITIES_POPULATION` collection. I.e: it's a single doc to keep populations for every city.

This code should work fine.

But is there a security rule to make sure that those writes are always going to be fired together? What if some malicious code fires a single write with only the 1st or the 2nd update?

What is the proper way of handling security for the scenario of a batched write?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check for batched writes in security rules, you can use the [`getAfter()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.getAfter) and [`existsAfter()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.existsAfter) functions. These return/check for the data as it exists after the write operation, **if** that write operation will be allowed.

So in your case you can check whether the `ALL_CITIES_POPULATION` document's `NYC` field after the write is the same as the `NYC` document's `population` field.